# Is there "absolute" point size for Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, random, output, generative-art, version-7

I would like to get points size that vary when the viewer is zooming in/out through the 3D graphic.  The point size I want should be defined as "absolute", relative to the coordinates used in the calculation.  Currently, the code below draw points that stay exactly of the same size on the screen, when we zoom in/out the viewing box, and this is annoying for what I want to achieve:

```
particles := RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 3}]

distribution := Graphics3D[{RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4}], PointSize -> 0.004, Point[particles]}]

Show[distribution,
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Boxed -> True,
    Ticks -> None,
    Background -> Black,
    ImageSize -> {700, 700},
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}
]
```

So is there a basic command that could be used in place of `PointSize -> 0.004`, to allow Mathematica to produce points of "absolute" size relative to the axes, i.e so that the point size vary when we zoom in/out the viewing box?

Comment: Have you see `AbsolutePointSize[]`? Maybe you want the opposite. I find "'absolute' size relative to..." a bit confusing, since absolute and relative have opposite meanings to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes, but currently it's doing the same effect than PointSize:  the points stay of the same size relative to the screen.  I need the size to vary relative  for the screen (maybe my wording isn't easy to understand).  The point size should vary when you move in the viewing box.  AbsolutePointSize doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you want `Sphere` (with a suitable radius) rather than `Point`. Generally, points have no size and are just rendered at a fixed size, while spheres have an actual size that is reflected in how big they are rendered.

Comment: @LukasLang, oh no, certainly NOT spheres!  This would slow down the output to a crawl.  My complete code renders several thousands of points, and it's in a manipulate environment.  So sphere is not an option here.  I really need round points.  Ideally, the size of the points on screen should vary with the view angle, so it stays the same relative to the coordinates.  I suspect Mathematica doesn't have a basic option for that.